# Regressing a data frame of multiple dependent variables on a data frame of multiple explanatory variables

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a data frame of multiple dependent variables called `dependents` and another data frame consisting of explanatory variables called `explanatory`. I want to regress each variable in `dependents` on all of the `explanatory` variables. However, whatever I do I keep getting (each time different) mistakes. I created a simpler version of my problem below:

```
dependents <- structure(list(exp1 = c(1,2,3), 
                             exp2 = c(4,5,6),
                             exp3 = c(7,8,9)),
                             .Names = c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3"),
                             class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

explanatory <- structure(list(var1 = c(1,2,3), 
                              var2 = c(4,5,6),
                              var3 = c(7,8,9)),
                             .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"),
                             class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I tried the following codes:

```
engel <- lm(dependents ~ exp_variables )

engel <- lm(colnames(dependents) ~ colnames(exp_variables))

engel <- lapply(colnames(dependents), function(x) {
         fit <- lm(paste(x,'~',colnames(exp_vars),collapse = "+")})

reg_data = cbind(dependents, exp_variables)
engel <- lm(dependents ~ exp_variables, data = reg_data )

reg_data = cbind(dependents, exp_variables)
engel <- lm(colnames(dependents) ~ colnames(exp_variables), data = reg_data )

engel <- lapply(dependents, function(x) {
         fit <- lm(paste(x,'~',exp_vars,collapse = "+")})

reg_data = cbind(dependents, exp_variables)
engel <- lapply(dependents, function(x) {
         fit <- lm(paste(x,'~',exp_vars,collapse = "+"), data=reg_data)})

reg_data = cbind(dependents, exp_variables)
engel <- lapply(colnames(dependents), function(x) {
         fit <- lm(paste(x,'~',colnames(exp_vars),collapse = "+"), data=reg_data)})
```

Can somebody please tell me what is the correct way to code this regression?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was great except that you should have provided matrices rather than data frames:

```
lm(as.matrix(dependents) ~ as.matrix(explanatory))
```

That, however, is for the case when `explanatory` doesn't include any factors. In the case of factors you could use

```
lm(as.matrix(dependents) ~ -1 + model.matrix(~ ., data = explanatory))
```

where I have `-1` as not to have two intercepts as `model.matrix` is going to create one column for it too. Of course there is always an option to be more straightforward and use, say, `lapply`:

```
lapply(dependents, function(y) lm(y ~ ., data = cbind(y = y, explanatory)))
```

which is actually perhaps even best as you can clearly control the formula of each model and the names of the regressors are nicely preserved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion with my original data and got this error:                                                                                                                    
  Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(4817L, 4817L, 4817L,  : 
  replacement has 122620 rows, data has 6131                                                     
My dependents data frame has 6131 rows, 19 columns, while my explanatory data frame have 6131 rows 20 columns

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz, what are `dim(dependents)` and `dim(explanatory)` in your case?

Comment: My dependents data frame has 6131 rows, 19 columns, while my explanatory data frame have 6131 rows 20 columns.

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz, hard to say, something must be going on with the data. You would need to upload it somewhere for me to help. As you can see, my answer does work with your simple minimal example.

Comment: I unfortunately can not upload the data because it is shared confidentially. However, do you think the issue might be due to the fact that I have some categorical and ordinal variables, along with integer and numeric ones, in my explanatory data?

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz, yes, that is the reason. I will update my answer.